# Return ALL table rows in an <OL> instead of only returning 2 out of 3

Tags: mysql

Trying to pull rows from a table and list them in an ol, however, my code only wants to return the last 2 out of the 3 total rows.

```
<?php
// Connects to your Database
mysql_connect("mysql.***.com", "***", "***") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("shpdb") or die(mysql_error());
$data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM savannah") or die(mysql_error());
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
?>
<h1>Dashboard</h1>
<h3>Manage and view documents.</h3>
<h5>Currently viewing Savannah's list of </h5>
<p><strong>List of patients:</strong></p>
<ol>
<?php
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
// Print out the contents of the entry
Print "<li><b>Name:</b> ".$info['name'] . " <br />";
Print "<b>ID:</b> ".$info['ID']." <br />";
Print "<b>Age:</b> ".$info['age'] ." <br />";
Print "<b>Location:</b> ".$info['location'] ." </li>";
 }
Print "</ol>"; ?>
```

The table "savannah" contains three rows, but like I said above, running this script only returns the last two.
Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does `echo "<pre>" . print_r($info,true) . "</pre>";` show three rows or just two? (To determine where the problem is)

Comment: Lukasz's answer worked perfectly... I just had to remove a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have

```
$info = mysql_fetch_array( $data );
```

used once before actual loop. Just remove the line below `mysql_query` procedure.

Comment: Thank you. Removed that line and now we're in business.